# Are Preserver and Defiler distinct classes?

Tags: adnd-2e, class, dark-sun

For example Fighter and Paladin are separate classes. They both belong to the warrior group, but are separate character classes.

For the purpose of class mechanics, are Preserver and Defiler separate character classes or the same?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, they are distinct classes.**

---

Let's analyze the main book:

From the [PHB (TSR2101)](/http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Player%27s_Handbook_2nd_edition):

> page26, 1st paragraph:
>   *"The complete character class descriptions (...) are organized according to groups."*

Therefore, the classes are filed under 4 great groups:

- Warrior
- Wizard
- Priest
- Rogue

> page 30, 1st paragraph:
>   *"The wizard group (...)"*

Followed by:

> Page 30, 2nd column, 2nd paragraph:
>   *"All wizards use table 20 for (...)"*

So, disagreeing with what Nvoigt wrote in his answer, **Wizard** is a group of classes. Of which **Mage** is your generic all-around wizard. Then you have the specialist wizards, each one being their own class.

It is also enforced in the page 44, under "Multi-Class Combinations". **Mage** is used in the available combos.

If you take a closer look at the classes chapter, the very text heading styles also point at this.

The entry for the groups is in a larger font than the entry for the individual classes, and all of those are in blue. So until page 44, every blue heading is either a group or a distinct character class.

So the specialist wizards are their own class. Mage is a distinct class.

**Now, onto the Dark Sun book.**

On the [Revised campaign boxed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Sun_Campaign_Setting,_Expanded_and_Revised), "The age of Heroes" book page 8 we have a table of the classes, again under their group heading:

> Table V: Class and Level Limits
>   (...)
>   *Wizard*
>    -  Defiler (De)
>    -  Preserver (Pr)
>   (...)

We already know that Wizard is a group of character classes, so Defiler and Preserver are the individual wizard-type classes available in that setting. Note that the standard mage is not available, as there is no magic <sub>(*cough* weave *cough*)</sub> energy to be used.

One more evidence, is this [interview with Troy Denning](http://www.athas.org/articles/Troy-Denning):

> The DS Rulebook presented the defiler and preserver as **separate and distinct classes**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 3):

Neither of them is a class. Wizard for example would be their class. Both are ways a magic user works in the Dark Sun campaign setting. You can be either one or the other, not both. So in contrast to classes, you could not take 2 levels of preserver and 3 of defilier, because both are wizard levels and you cannot multiclass the same class, as you could do with Warrior and Paladin for example.